# Azure AD Connect parses email field as new UPN

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

We are trying to set up Azure AD connect, but we seem unable to get to the situation we desire.
Our current situation is a local AD where we fill in the email field for all users (and all external users). Our admins have a normal and an admin account. The email for the adminaccount is the same for all. We don't have Exchange linked to AD, nor do we yet have the possibility to set up ADFS.

I've been trying to set up the sync for the admins only. So let's assume the following situation:

- Account 1:

  - SamAccountName: Admin1
  - UPN: admin1@company.com
  - Email: Admin@company.com
- Account 2:

  - SamAccountName: Admin2
  - UPN: admin2@company.com
  - Email: admin@company.com

Our first sync stopped after the first one, with the message that the UPN is duplicate.
When checking, AAD had 1 account:

- Account 1:

  - UPN: admin@tenant.onmicrosoft.com

So, I undid everything and started from scratch. This time, I changed account 2 to not have an email. This is the result:

- Account 1:

  - UPN: admin@tenant.onmicrosoft.com
- Account 2:

  - UPN: admin2@tenant.onmicrosoft.com

So basically, we want our UPN to be like SamAccountName@tenant.onmicrosoft.com, but it seems like we need to clear the email field, sync and fill it again. A lot of our internal tools use the email field currently, which makes it quite impossible.

I tried changing the Azure AD connect setup as well, to change the place where they ask for UPN to SamAccountName, but either I get errors or it doesn't work. What am I missing.

We also have accounts for external partners, something like this:

- SamAccountName: partner_userx
- UPN: partner_userx@company.com
- email: someuser@externalpartner.com

If I sync this, the AAD UPN was someuser@tenant.onmicrosoft.com.

If I set up everyting in staging and take a look at csexport output, I see nothing special. Just the properties described as they are on my local AD.

For some reason the Sync uses the mail field, which I do not want.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delayed response. Azure AD is picking up the email address as the UPN prefix value and appending your initial domain (e.g. @tenant.onmicrosoft.com) simply because the UPN suffix being sync'ed from on-premises is not valid/not verified domain. If you have the AD:UserPrincipalName set on-premises and its UPN suffix is a Verified Domain on your Azure tenant it should work as you expect. Meaning, you'll get the expected UPN value in Azure AD, if you sync a UPN suffix with a domain that is verified on the tenant (either a custom domain or the tenant's initial domain).
Taking the example provided:

- SamAccountName: partner_userx
- UPN: partner_userx@company.com
- email: someuser@externalpartner.com

You need to either:
a) set the on-premises UPN as partner_userx@tenant.onmicrosoft.com instead, or;
b) verify the domain 'company.com' on your Azure AD tenant

If neither of these options are feasible then you'll have to work on some advanced sync rule customization (which is not supported) to map an alternative AD attribute to serve as the source attribute for the UPN and set this attribute with the alternative UPN value containing a verified domain suffix (e.g: extensionAttribute10 = partner_userx@tenant.onmicrosoft.com)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. We current worked around it by not syncing the mail field.
We are transitioning from another tenant and cannot attach the domainname yet.

after the transition, we could add the mail field again and try with a test account.
We are seeing the same behaviour in the proxy addresses, (exchange does not pick up aliases yet) so probably this will be resolved as soon as the domain name is attached as well.

Thanks for taking the time to reply, this gives us hope that everything will turn out alright.